# User.find_by(["name LIKE ?" not working on heroku but working on development server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

What would cause this to work in development, but not production?

I have `User.find_by(["name LIKE ?", "DAN DOUGHTY"])`

and it finds the user with the name `"Dan Doughty"` on development server but does not find that same user in Production on Heroku. There is a User with that name on both environments.

Comment: Also... this was working for a week and suddenly stopped working today.

Comment: Are you using postgres? Also note case-sensitivity, may be you need `ILIKE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that `LIKE` is case sensitive and it will match the exact string

So either downcase the name both side

```
User.find_by(["lower(name) LIKE ?", "DAN DOUGHTY".downcase])
```

Or go for `ILIKE`

```
User.find_by(["name ILIKE ?", "DAN DOUGHTY"])
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I am just going to use something more reliable. I chose to use Arel to fix this issue.

They’re unfortunately just a little buried and a little undocumented. And so conventional wisdom is that Rails doesn’t do case-insensitive finds. But in fact it does:

case-insensitively:

```
t = User.arel_table
User.find_by(t[:name].matches('DAN DOUGHTY'))
```

Comment: I had the same issue when I was using SQLite in development and then deploying to heroku with a postgresql database. Another reason to make your development environment as close to production as possible 

Comment: that seems exactly what the problem is